# Command to add asterisk before some items in nested lists, independent of the level

Tags: enumitem

I am using enumitem package to deal with lists, in some cases nested ones. I would like to define a command `\staritem` to add an asterisk before an item not depending of knowing the level of the nested list. For example, the code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\staritem{???}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item Item 1
 \staritem Item 2
 \item Item 3
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item Item 3.1
  \item Item 3.2
  \staritem Item 3.3
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

should output:

(a) Item 1

*(b) Item 2

(c) Item 3

(i) Item 3.1

(ii) Item 3.2

*(iii) Item 3.3

I know that `\item[*\theenumi]` and `\item[*\theenumii]` do the job, but I would like the flexbility of not inform the level of nested enumerate environment.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current counter name is accessible as `\@enumctr`.

Remove the line with `\@currentlabel` if you don't want that cross-references to the starred items have the *.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\staritem{%
  \par\refstepcounter{\@enumctr}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{*\@currentlabel}%
  \item[{\makebox[0pt][r]{*}}\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{test}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item Item 1
 \staritem\label{test} Item 2
 \item Item 3
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item Item 3.1
  \item Item 3.2
  \staritem Item 3.3
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But in order cross-references work for starred items I had to redefine the label as `\edef\@currentlabel{*\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}%`

Comment: @rla It works with my approach.

Comment: I tried `\staritem\label{mylabeltest} Item 3` and `\ref{mylabeltest}` returned (b) instead of (c). I will check it more carefully. Anyway, thank you for the answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @rla Sorry, but I added other `\label` commands and I see no problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\staritem{\item[*\csname theenum\roman{enumi}\endcsname]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item Item 1
 \staritem Item 2
 \item Item 3
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item Item 3.1
  \item Item 3.2
  \staritem Item 3.3
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The counter is not printed, only the asterisk and the parenthesis.

Comment: @rla ... Not sure what you did... Possibly you forgot `enumitem` package. See my screenshot (added on this edit. Nothing else changed)

Comment: I will check it more carefully. Maybe I am missing something in my particular document. Anyway, thank you for the answer, it is clean and elegant.